# Obscure/Protect Javascript Source Code in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: javascript, security, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

As you might know, in Windows 8 (Metro/RT/WinJS) apps, when they are acquired from the windows app store and installed to a local computer, all the original source code javascript files are clearly viewable in the windows filesystem.

As such, is there some way that I can obscure, hide, or protect the javascript code so as to avoid the possibility of it being stolen and used to make a new app?
At the very least, I'd like it to be a bit harder than for someone to just open the folder and read the code in it's original state....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up some notes on the options you have for Windows 8/8.1: http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/04/04/protecting-your-code/. Windows 10 might offer some better options. For example, the Hosted Web App option described on http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/06/project-westminster-in-a-nutshell/ will let you keep lots of code on the server. But I haven't looked at everything that's being done there.

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion, what would be the best way to setup minification/obfuscating of the javascript in the app's visual studio project? (The app needs to work offline, so the hosted method won't work)

Comment: Because the JS files in your solution just go straight into the final package, and because there's not a "compile" step per se, I think the easiest way to do this is to create a script that will take copy your VS project structure to another folder, then go through and minify all the applicable files overwriting the originals. Then open that solution to build the package that will then include the minified versions. If you minify in the solution used for debugging, that'll just be a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Look into minification[1], like the Closure compiler: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

[1]http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add this or similar types of minification into the visual studio build sequence that takes place on app debug/deploy?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but it seems possible. E.g. http://encosia.com/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/